# What's the default TCP window size of iperf3?

Tags: tcp, iperf

Does anyone know what's the default TCP window size for `iperf3`? It is not mentioned in the [manual](https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php#3doc) and I also can't find it in the output, when running a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best running a packet capture (Wireshark/tcpdump) to see what iperf is using by default on your system.

Personally, I'm seeing 29200 Bytes on Linux and 65535 on Windows.